# Count a pivoted dataframe columns and join to another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two pandas dataframes, related to a call center:

```
> my_call
  id call_id            result code_result
1  1     200 answering machine          am
2  2     200         call back          cb
3  3     200         call_back          cb
4  4     300    still workable          sw
5  5     300     transfer call          tc
6  6     300       do not call          dc

> my_lead
  lead_id lead_source
1     200        bpos
2     300        zeta
```

I want to join these two datasets, by `call_id` and `lead id`, but I want `code_result` to pivot in a wide manner so as to count the results per id and have an additional column to count the `lead_id`s. This is the expected result:

```
  lead_id lead_source am cb sw tc dc count
1     200        bpos 1  2  0  0  0  3
2     300        zeta 0  0  1  1  1  3
```

I think a join from `my_lead` could be ok but I'm stuck in how to do it, and if I have to type all the results `(am, cb, sw, tc, dc)` or if it's possible that python can do it automatically. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option via [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab) + [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join):

```
import pandas as pd

my_call = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6},
    'call_id': {1: 200, 2: 200, 3: 200, 4: 300, 5: 300, 6: 300},
    'result': {1: 'answering machine ', 2: 'call back', 3: 'call_back',
               4: 'still workable', 5: 'transfer call', 6: 'do not call'},
    'code_result': {1: 'am', 2: 'cb', 3: 'cb', 4: 'sw', 5: 'tc', 6: 'dc'}
})
my_lead = pd.DataFrame({
    'lead_id': {1: 200, 2: 300}, 'lead_source': {1: 'bpos', 2: 'zeta'}
})

new_df = my_lead.join(
    pd.crosstab(my_call['call_id'], my_call['code_result'],
                margins=True,
                margins_name='count'),
    on='lead_id'
)

print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
  lead_id lead_source  am  cb  dc  sw  tc  count
1     200        bpos   1   2   0   0   0      3
2     300        zeta   0   0   1   1   1      3
```

---

An option via [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas-series-str-get-dummies) + [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join):

```
import pandas as pd

my_call = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6},
    'call_id': {1: 200, 2: 200, 3: 200, 4: 300, 5: 300, 6: 300},
    'result': {1: 'answering machine ', 2: 'call back', 3: 'call_back',
               4: 'still workable', 5: 'transfer call', 6: 'do not call'},
    'code_result': {1: 'am', 2: 'cb', 3: 'cb', 4: 'sw', 5: 'tc', 6: 'dc'}
})
my_lead = pd.DataFrame({
    'lead_id': {1: 200, 2: 300}, 'lead_source': {1: 'bpos', 2: 'zeta'}
})

new_df = my_call.set_index('call_id')['code_result'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
new_df['count'] = new_df.sum(axis=1)
new_df = my_lead.join(new_df, on='lead_id')
print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
   lead_id lead_source  am  cb  dc  sw  tc  count
1      200        bpos   1   2   0   0   0      3
2      300        zeta   0   0   1   1   1      3
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Henry Ecker, I saw that `code_result` was converted to string, wasn't it? Two great answers!

Comment: Code_result is already a string. Which is why `str get_dummies` could be used. I'd say that the crosstab option is the better way to go, but you'll have to play around on your actual dataset.

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
result = (
    df2.merge(
        df.pivot_table(
            index=['call_id'],
            columns='code_result',
            values='id',
            aggfunc='count',
            fill_value=0,
            margins=True,
            margins_name='Count')
        .reset_index(),
        left_on='lead_id',
        right_on='call_id',
        how='left')
)
```

`NOTE`: Take advantage of `margins` to evaluate the `Count` column.